# syntax error in bash "if.. elif" script

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, syntax, cp

I'm trying to build my first script to use "if" statements in bash. It combines 2 scripts that I got working to create multiple copies of a file, one with names appended numerically, the other using A-Z.

I've tried many changes but I absolutely cannot get this to work without the error message

> ./cpmany.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
>   ./cpmany.sh: line 18:`elif [ $alpha="A" ]; then'

Here is my original, non-working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo "input file source"
read INPUT
echo  "Alphabetical or Numerical"
read alpha
if [ $alpha=="N" ]; then
echo "start of range"
read x
echo "end of range"
read y
    for ((i=x; i<=y; i++)); do cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i";
elif [ $alpha=="A" ]; then
    for i in {a..z}
    do
    echo "$i"
    cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i";
else
    echo "error in selection";
fi
exit 0
```

Here is my current code with added "done"s and spaces in the if [ $alpha = "N" ]

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "input file source"
read INPUT
echo  "Alphabetical or Numerical"
read alpha


if [ $alpha = "N" ]; then
echo "start of range"
read x
echo "end of range"
read y

    for ((i=x; i<=y; i++)); do cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i";
done
elif [ $alpha = "A" ]; then
    for i in {a..z};
    do
    echo "$i"
    cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i"; done
else
    echo "error in selection";
fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: You'll also need to put spaces around the `=` in your test conditions, like so: `[ "$alpha" = "N" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close the `for` loop with `done`.

Comment: I added "done" to the line after the fi, still getting the same error

Comment: Added a second one on the line before the "elif", and now it gives this error:
>./cpmany.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
> ./cpmany.sh: line 23: `else'

Comment: This is my code now that I've closed the loops with "done"
`#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo "input file source"
read INPUT
echo  "Alphabetical or Numerical"
read alpha


if [ $alpha="N" ]; then

echo "start of range"
read x
echo "end of range"
read y

        for ((i=x; i<=y; i++)); do cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i";
done
elif [ $alpha="A" ]; then
        for i in {a..z}
        do
        echo "$i"
        cp "$INPUT" "$INPUT$i";
else
        echo "error in selection";
fi
done
exit 0
`

Comment: Second `for` loop misses semicolon in front of `do` and lacks `done`

Comment: change if [ $alpha="N" ]; then to if [ $alpha = "N" ]; then

Comment: @user2921342: Please don't put multi-line code blocks on comments; as you can see, they don't format well. You can update the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson my apologies, I have now updated my code in the original post.
It kinda works now, but gives me this error:
>./cpmany.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
>./cpmany.sh: line 24: `done'

Comment: @user2921342: Please don't update the code in a way that fixes the problem you were asking about and invalidates existing answers. Instead, you can add a new version of the code if you want to follow up.

Comment: @KeithThompson I added the original code back into the question